# Update dictionary and create key-value pairs with loop values

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, for-loop

i'm trying to append to a dictionary. there are two loops. the name of the keys depends on the value of the inner loop and the key is the value of a variable which is updated within the loop. my script is

```
def append_value(dict_obj, key, value):
    # Check if key exist in dict or not
    if key in dict_obj:
        # Key exist in dict.
        # Check if type of value of key is list or not
        if not isinstance(dict_obj[key], list):
            # If type is not list then make it list
            dict_obj[key] = [dict_obj[key]]
        # Append the value in list
        dict_obj[key].append(value)
    else:
        # As key is not in dict,
        # so, add key-value pair
        dict_obj[key] = value

for x in range(tot):
  dict=['output'=x]

  for a in range(33,91):
        index_val=(a*sum_t)/x        

        # now i'm trying to create key names that would be year_33 year_34 and so on
        head=''
        head='year_{}'.format(a)

        append_value(dict, head=avg_PMI)
```

i get the error name 'append_value' is not defined. would appreciate any help. i would like to loop over values of tot and the (33,91) range. each combination of the two gives a unique values and i want to create a dictionary which will become a csv where x values are rows, a is the column.

thanks!

edited: to show append_value function

Comment: What do you expect `append_value` to be? Did you define it somewhere? Also, this seems like a syntax error: `dict=['output'=x]` what is that supposed to do?

Comment: What do you mean by "append to a dictionary"? Why do you **expect** `append_value` to be defined? Please provide more clarity about your question.

Comment: Don't name your dictionary `dict` - it shadows the type and may cause problems elsewhere in your program (as well as being confusing). Assuming you name your dictionary something like `my_data`, what's wrong with `my_data['output'] = x` and `my_data[head] = avg_PMI` - please read the basics on dictionary use in Python https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: thank you for your comments. i have updated the code to show the append_value function definition. there was an error there which i corrected but i now get the error "append_value() got an unexpected keyword argument 'head'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the error is that when you call a function with `head=avg_PMI`, python assumes that `head` is an argument. For `append_value`, the only arguments are `dict_obj`, `key` and `value`. I assume that you want to add a value to the dictionary such that head=avg_PMI. To do this, you have to call the function `append_value` in the following way:
`append_value(dict, head, avg_PMI)`.